# Saving options of an excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, web-services

I am generating an excel file on button click from webpage using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` .Now the problem that i am getting is that the generating file is getting saved into the localdisk of the system .Means the path is hardcoded..here is my code.

```
        object objOpt = Missing.Value;
        objBook.SaveAs(@"D:\SampleChart.xls", objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt, objOpt);
        objBook.Close(false, objOpt, objOpt);
```

So my question is how can i save this excel file from the browser.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You don't.  This is a direct quote from Microsoft's web site: "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."  If you insist on doing, it, you'll have to create your own open/save dialog box, since Excel is running on the server and your browser could be open anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Please use 
`objBook.SaveCopyAs("filename");`
instead of `objBook.SaveAs();`